# NEWBIE: Is CiviCRM RIGHT FOR US

Tags: joomla, evaluating-civicrm

I have a nonprofit organization who wants to manage their members and create a paperless membership management environment. Some of the specific, out of the box needs are:

1. The ability to manage roles and functions within the organization, such as executive board members, officers, chairpersons, committee assignments, etc.
2. Pay dues with installment options and late fees
3. Customizable member profile options
4. Manage events
5. Manage yearly obligations

The interface would be for internal use only, sort of an intranet. There would be no outside membership subscriptions. We are currently on a Joomla platform. Can CiviCRM interface. Is this a good choice?

Comment: Have you tried one of the CiviCRM demos? That might give you a feel for how CiviCRM works. https://civicrm.org/demo

Answer (score 2):

It's an excellent choice for you. I've run Civi on both WordPress and Joomla and it does everything you are asking and more. Right now, I have at least a half dozen sites under my care on both Joomla and Wordpress. Depending on the size of your organization, Joomla may be the perfect, especially if the client is already accustomed to using Joomla. The ACL will probably be a little more familiar than in a WordPress environment.

Comment: Agreed, it would make perfect sense to use CiviCRM for this. If Joomla is not a hard requirement you might think about a move to Wordpress (more used in the CiviCRM community) but it would be fine with Joomla too. If privacy of data is an issue you might contemplate separating the CiviCRM database from your public website (check https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/ for more information)

Answer (score 1):

I think CiviCRM decision is very well. Your scenario is almost textbook solution of what CiviCRM is designed for. On the CMS level, I wouldn't insist on Wordpress.

In my experience it plays quite well by the cases with few users and/or users with similar permissions. But when you need a more complex user administration process it needs plugins and stuff (which is OK for the many admins actually but I love to keep it simple).

I would actually suggest Drupal for user management abilities but Joomla looks promising as well. And it seems that people in the organization already familiar with its management, so it'd be a good choice.

Comment: Thank you so much loker for your feedback. The were attempting to use Wild Apricot, but I keep running into brick walls. Is CiviCRM fairly intuitive for a mid-level designer/developer?

Comment: Well, I've tried the Civi several years ago and find difficult to understand but I had no kind of crm experience at that time. After used Salesforce for a year, Civi was quite easy to set up and use. Also the community loves sharing... Both the little extensions and plugins they develop and the documentation... So I guess you will find your way, but it's up to your experience at the end.

Comment: You can do quite a bit out of the box with Civi. It does help to work with a CiviCRM partner for hosting and setting everything up. This way you will have the benefit of experience, instead of trying to figure out everything on your own. Set aside a budget for hosting, setup and ongoing support, so you don't run into issues in the long-term. Check this out for more background information. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-civicrm-community/the-civicrm-community/